# Boost. How to run one test unit inside another one?

Tags: c++, unit-testing, boost

I need to run a test unit at the beginning of the current one.
I have tried BOOST_TEST_INVOKE_IF_N_ARGS with no results.

Comment: I'm wondering where this requirement comes from. It's usually best to make tests independent of each other. Can you give some more details on the context and why this is necessary?

Comment: what is your boost version?

Answer (score 3):

You can [manage test dependencies](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_67_0/libs/test/doc/html/boost_test/tests_organization/tests_dependencies.html):

> Decorator [`depends_on`](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_67_0/libs/test/doc/html/boost_test/utf_reference/test_org_reference/decorator_depends_on.html) associates the decorated test case (call it TB) with another test case (call it TA) specified by name. This affects the processing the test tree in two ways. First, test case TA is ordered to be run before TB, irrespective of the order in which they were declared or added to the test tree. Second, the execution of TB is skipped if TA is either disabled or skipped or is executed and marked as failed.

```
#define BOOST_TEST_MODULE decorator_07
#include <boost/test/included/unit_test.hpp>

namespace utf = boost::unit_test;

// test1 and test2 defined at the bottom

BOOST_AUTO_TEST_CASE(test3, * utf::depends_on("s1/test1"))
{
  BOOST_TEST(false);
}

BOOST_AUTO_TEST_CASE(test4, * utf::depends_on("test3"))
{
  BOOST_TEST(false);
}

BOOST_AUTO_TEST_CASE(test5, * utf::depends_on("s1/test2"))
{
  BOOST_TEST(false);
}

BOOST_AUTO_TEST_SUITE(s1)

  BOOST_AUTO_TEST_CASE(test1)
  {
    BOOST_TEST(true);
  }

  BOOST_AUTO_TEST_CASE(test2, * utf::disabled())
  {
    BOOST_TEST(false);
  }

BOOST_AUTO_TEST_SUITE_END()
```

Prints

```
> decorator_07 --report_level=detailed
Running 4 test cases...
test.cpp(10): error: in "test3": check false has failed

Test module "decorator_07" has failed with:
  1 test case out of 4 passed
  1 test case out of 4 failed
  2 test cases out of 4 skipped
  1 assertion out of 2 passed
  1 assertion out of 2 failed

  Test case "test3" has failed with:
    1 assertion out of 1 failed

  Test case "test4" was skipped
  Test case "test5" was skipped
  Test suite "s1" has passed with:
    1 test case out of 1 passed
    1 assertion out of 1 passed

    Test case "s1/test1" has passed with:
      1 assertion out of 1 passed
```